# Check if user has a permission with specific codename in django

Tags: django, django-permissions

I am trying to check if a user has a permission, which I have defined in the `class Meta` of the model, with a specific codename. At the moment I have:

```
if request.user.has_perm('app_label.code_name'):
    do something
```

What I am trying to avoid is using the app_label, however using `has_perm('code_name')` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The way this function works is that you need to pass the app_label, so not much you can do there.

One workaround can be to write your own wrapper function, something like:

```
def _has_perm(user, code_name, app_label="app_label"):
    return user.has_perm(app_label + "." + code_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but my idea was to check if a certain user has a permission with `code_name = x` for example, without giving the `app_label`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to provide the app label is that permissions are application specific. That means if you have two apps, `app_a` and `app_b`, both with a model named `Farm`, they could both have a permission called `can_create_new_chickens`. It is very important to understand that there are two separate permissions here:

- `app_a.farm.can_create_new_chickens`
- `app_b.farm.can_create_new_chickens`

These are independent permissions, and a user can have neither, both or one or the other. This means it would be insecure to validate permissions without referring to the application name. Permissions given to a user in one application could affect their permissions in another application.

Back to your question, the answer is no, you cannot check permissions without the application name for the reasons given above.